# Using request.env Inside Rails Middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, passenger, middleware

I am trying to use Passenger's request variable within my Rails middleware so I can send information to an OmniAuth strategy:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :casmate, {
    :setup => true,
    :dn    => request.env['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN']
  }
end
```

but "request" isn't recognized within the middleware.  Is there a way to do this within the middleware, or is there a way to invoke the middleware in a controller and pass in the same symbols (:casmate, :setup, :dn)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to use the request.env variable within a middleware initializer, but if you want to send any information, you can do so within the options hash by:

```
request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:dn] = request.env['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN']
```

inside of your controller.